# Finding the distance traveled when moving in a discrete arc

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am working on a small game and ended up with a problem which can be simplified to this:

---

**Problem:**

I am standing at $(0, 0)$ and I want to get to $(1, 1)$.

To begin with my direction is $(0, 1)$.

I will move $N$ times.

Each 'move' consists of me walking in my direction $x$ units, and then turning $90/(N - 1)$ degrees.

in terms of $N$, write $x$.

---

I can see that $x$ approaches $\pi/(2N)$ as I increase N

also:

$N = 2, x = 1$

$N = 3, x = 2 - \sqrt2$

but I cannot figure out any sort of general case or how to even begin

Comment: You essentially move on the arc of a circle whose endpoints are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, so the problem boils down to performing simple trigonometry on a regular $8N$-agon.

Comment: not really, for example the case N = 2, I travel to point (0, 1), rotate 90 degrees then travel to point (1, 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the sum of the horizontal distances under each line segment must add to $1$. Given that each line segment has length $x$ and that the angle between each line segment and the $x$-axis decreases by $\pi/(2N-2)$ after each move, it follows that

$$
x = \left[1 + \sum_{k=1}^{N-2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2(N - 1)}\right)\right]^{-1} = \left[\sum_{k=0}^{N-2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2(N - 1)}\right)\right]^{-1},~~N \geq 2
$$

You can show that $x \to 0$ and $Nx \to \pi/2$ in the limit as $N \to \infty$, as we would expect.